# Range with custom thumb doesn't reach the end of track, CSS

Tags: css, ionic-framework, range

I try to find out the problem but since i'm not css guru I need the help.

I have slider and I try to set custom image on `slider-thumb`.

The issue is: `slider-thumb` minimum and maximum position do not reach at the end of range:

This is a demo I play with:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbLvbg) - try to move thumb bottom-up

---

This is a code (BTW I use Ionic)

```
<div class="aa-volume wm-volume-range range" style="position: absolute;top: 3rem;left: 0rem;">                            
                        <input type="range" name="volume"                                    
                               min="0" max="100" 
                               value="{{displayDevice.fan_volume.value}}" ng-model="displayDevice.fan_volume.value" integer
       style="max-width: 8rem;width: 8rem;min-width: 8rem;">                              
 </div>
```

and css:

```
.wm-volume-range.range {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.wm-volume-range.range i.icon {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.wm-volume-range.range span {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.aa-volume input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
             width: 38px;
             height: 16px;

             border-radius: 0px;
             background-image: url('http://www.lesliesanford.com/vst/knobman/files/slider-thumbs/SimpleSliderThumb.png'),

             -webkit-gradient(
                 linear,
                 left top,
                 left bottom,
                 color-stop(1, #a1a1a1)
             );
             -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
             background-size: 48px 24px;
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-position: 50%;

}
```

Can anybody help to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you `rotate` your thumb it keeps its center and it doesn't reach the end of the track. If you don't rotate it, it [works](http://codepen.io/misterdev/pen/mExyqo)

1. The easiest way would be to rotate the file image before setting it as the `background-image` of your range thumb.
2. Otherwise, you can create a custom thumb and move it to follow the real hidden cursor. You can see an example [here](http://codepen.io/misterdev/pen/xOYqdj) (the second range).